# Raspberry Pi Zero - Does Not Boot Unless Pressing On the Processor With My Thumb?

Tags: pi-zero-w

Riddle me this. Why with a tested functional and adequate power supply, does this PI ZERO only blink the led and boot when i am pressing on it with my thumb? SD Card and software are good.

Comment: Sounds like a defect - if still under warranty I would follow up with the supplier. otherwise, I would get a new Pi.

Comment: Probably right. It just strange that it worked flawlessly for months and then without dropping it etc, just went south. It's curious that when I plug it in and then hold my thumb on the processor, it works. And the when I remove my thumb it turns off...BUT when I press again it does not turn on again UNLESS I remove the power source and replug it and then have my thumb again on the processor. Strange.

Comment: it may be that it is not the processor that is getting pressed

Comment: A bad solder joint could break just based on temperature swing (getting hot from running the pi, cooling when its turned off) but was probably not great to start with.